# Signing a string with the Azure Key Vault Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, digital-signature, azure-keyvault, azure-python-sdk

I am looking to sign a string with a certificate created and stored inside Azure Key Vault. I am using the Python SDK provided by Microsoft to fetch the certificate. I proceed to extract the private key from the decoded certificate secret.

Obtaining the private key in this manor is a problem, as it doesn't allow me to use the private key with CryptographyClient. I receive an error, which is expected and shown beneath, as the private key is not a KeyVaultKey instance.

The error I am facing:

```py
Exception has occurred: ValueError
'key' must be a KeyVaultKey instance or a key ID string
  File "C:\Users\P.Markham\OneDrive - Royal Terberg Group B.V\Documents\SSF\init.py", line 31, in <module>
    cryptography_client = CryptographyClient(private_key, credential=credential)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: 'key' must be a KeyVaultKey instance or a key ID string
```

The code I am using is shown beneath:

```py
import os
import hashlib
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs12
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
from azure.keyvault.keys.crypto import SignatureAlgorithm
from azure.keyvault.certificates import CertificateClient
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.keyvault.keys.crypto import CryptographyClient, EncryptionAlgorithm

VAULT_URL = os.environ["AZURE_VAULT_URL"]
CERTIFICATE_NAME = os.environ["AZURE_CERTIFICATE_NAME"]

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
certificate_client = CertificateClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credential)
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credential)

certificate_secret = secret_client.get_secret(name=CERTIFICATE_NAME)

cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(certificate_secret.value)
private_key, public_certificate, additional_certificates = pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates(
    data=cert_bytes,
    password=None
)
print(f"Certificate with name '{certificate_secret.name}' was parsed.")

digest = hashlib.sha256(b"an example string i want to sign").digest()
cryptography_client = CryptographyClient(private_key, credential=credential)

# sign returns the signature and the metadata required to verify it
result = cryptography_client.sign(SignatureAlgorithm.rs256, digest)
print(f"Key ID: {result.key_id}")
print(f"Algorithm: {result.algorithm}")
print(f"Signature: {result.signature}")
signature = result.signature
```

How do I sign a string with a certificate? I feel like I'm going about this the complete wrong way, but I cant find any documentation that links signing with certificates.

Comment: Having done more research, it seems that calling get_key on a certificate may include both the private and public key in some way. I believe this because of the Rest API documentation:

`The SIGN operation is applicable to asymmetric and symmetric keys stored in Azure Key Vault since this operation uses the private portion of the key. This operation requires the keys/sign permission.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the certificate to perform cryptographic operations, you can just use the key by the same name directly -- there shouldn't be a need to parse a key out from the certificate secret. For example:

```py
import hashlib
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
from azure.keyvault.keys.crypto import CryptographyClient, SignatureAlgorithm

VAULT_URL = os.environ["AZURE_VAULT_URL"]
CERTIFICATE_NAME = os.environ["AZURE_CERTIFICATE_NAME"]

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
key_client = KeyClient(VAULT_URL, credential)
cert_key = key_client.get_key(CERTIFICATE_NAME)

digest = hashlib.sha256(b"an example string i want to sign").digest()
cryptography_client = CryptographyClient(cert_key, credential)

result = cryptography_client.sign(SignatureAlgorithm.rs256, digest)
print(f"Key ID: {result.key_id}")
print(f"Algorithm: {result.algorithm}")
print(f"Signature: {result.signature}")
signature = result.signature
```

Comment: I eventually figured this out yesterday, but I wanted someone to cross-verify as I has a small concern I might be signing with the public key. Thank you.